# How do I skip XML tags?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse some XML dealing with location. Here is a sample of the XML.

```
<location>
    <city lat="51.5078" lng="-0.128" displayName="London">
        <country displayName="UK"/>
    </city>
    <metroArea lat="51.5078" lng="-0.128" displayName="London" id="24426">
        <country displayName="UK"/>
    </metroArea>
</location>
<location>
    <city lat="42.9833" lng="-81.25" displayName="London">
        <country displayName="Canada"/>
        <state displayName="ON"/>
    </city>
    <metroArea lat="42.9833" lng="-81.25" displayName="London" id="27374">
        <country displayName="Canada"/>
        <state displayName="ON"/>
    </metroArea>
</location>
```

In the above XML London, UK does not have a state but London, Canada does. My results when parsing are

- London, ON
- UK
- London, KY
- Canada

How do I skip the "state" tag to achieve the following results?

- London
- UK
- London, ON
- Canada

This is the Java code I am using.

```
private void addCitiesToHashmap(List<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems, String xml) 
    {
        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();

        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml);

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_METRO_AREA);
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) 
        {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            map.put(KEY_ID, e.getAttribute(KEY_ID));
            NodeList nl3 = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_CITY);
            {
                Element g = (Element) nl3.item(i);
                map.put(KEY_DISPLAY_NAME , g.getAttribute(KEY_DISPLAY_NAME ));
            }
            NodeList nl4 = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_COUNTRY);
            {
                Element h = (Element) nl4.item(i);
                map.put(KEY_DISPLAY_NAME_4 + "3" , h.getAttribute(KEY_DISPLAY_NAME_4 ));
            }
            NodeList nl2 = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_STATE);
            {
                Element f = (Element) nl2.item(i);
                if (f != null)
                    map.put(KEY_DISPLAY_NAME_2 + "2" , f.getAttribute(KEY_DISPLAY_NAME_2 ));

                menuItems.add(map);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where is Kentucky coming from in your sample XML?

Comment: These are just the first two of 13 XML locations. Of course there is London, KY; London, OH; etc. So Kentucky was the next location.

Comment: Please clarify the business logic of your requirements: do you need to "skip" a state in just a first row, or in every row? Rgds,

Comment: Basically if a tag isn't there, don't include it in the map for that location. The "state" tag can be missing in any row.

Comment: You want to work on a &lt;location> basis, I guess. Pairing up each location/city and loaction/country with an additional location/metroaarea/state, if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement definition, in order to "skip" the state field from the first record you can use `Substring()` method in conjunction with `IndexOf(',')` in order to find the position of the comma and remove the following part